# Node.js Firestore Query Select List of field paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I try to create and returns a new Query instance that applies a field mask to the result and returns only the specified subset of fields.

When i use :

```
let query = firestore.collection('col').select('field1','field2','field3').get() ...
```

it's ok, the query returns all the collection documents with only the 3 specified fields.

In my context application, the specified fields list is on a configuration document. When i use :

```
let fieldsList = ['field1','field2','field3'];    
let query = firestore.collection('col').select(fieldsList).get() ...
```

i have an error message "Argument at index 0 is not a valid FieldPath ..."

On the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.13.x/Query#select), it is specified "*You can specify a list of field paths to return*"

So, i don't know how to pass a list of field paths to the query select method.

Many thanks for your help !!!

Comment: try this: `let query = firestore.collection('col').select(...fieldsList).get() ..` (notice the triple dots just before `fieldsList`

Comment: That's run, thank you very much for your very fast help !!!

Comment: Great, I've moved my comment to answer field, please mark it as chosen answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are working on what is known as [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
To make it work, it need to add triple dots in front of `fieldList`:

```
let query = firestore.collection('col').select(...fieldsList).get() ..
```