# How to read firebase document in node

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I already know there are countless questions already posted about this, but none of them seem to work for me, despite every attempt. I am utilizing import statements instead of require in node, which is my best guess at why the solutions for others don't work for me.

Here is an example:

```
const messaging = doc(firestore, "Students", 'AOAZBBlgybeFKtxnMluEHvGYJ403');
    console.log(messaging.get());
```

Get is not a function.

Same issue here but with select, and if I remove the select get is still not a function:

```
const result = firestore.document.collection('Students').doc('AOAZBBlgybeFKtxnMluEHvGYJ403').select('Distance').get();
    console.log(result.docs)
```

I'm quite lost at this point, trying everything then forgetting what I have already tried so I end up trying the same failed things again. The programmers credo. Anyway, any help would be much appreciated.

Ah, and here is some more info in case it is helpful:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { doc, updateDoc, setDoc, increment } from "firebase/firestore";
var firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
var storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);
var auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the newer modular SDKs of v9 and above, which use a new modular syntax.

Instead of:

```
messaging.get()
```

You should now do:

```
getDoc(messaging)
```

Don't forget to add the `getDoc` to your `import` statement.

For more on this, see the v9 code samples in the Firebase documentation, like here on [getting a single document from Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-9_1).

Comment: Halllelujah! Thanks! It worked! 
Also, would you happen to know how to use the "select" function. I need some way to read only a specific document, so the firebase security rules of other documents within a collection dont prevent me from reading because getDoc reads every field?

Comment: This seem to show that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646744/node-js-firestore-query-select-list-of-field-paths

Comment: I apologize for pushing another question, but I seem to be having the same issue as with get(). But this time theres no such function called "selectDoc".

Comment: In that case, how would I switch my firebase mode from v9 to node?

Comment: Is there a different import statement for them?

Comment: Yeah, so I think you're not actually using the Admin SDK for Node.js, but are using the client-side SDK. And in that case, `select` is not available - as it doesn't exist in the client-side SDKs.